# Delphi Windows Subsystem Linux Debugging not working

Tags: linux, delphi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am facing a problem debugging Delphi Linux application on WSL.
I have a machine running Ubuntu 20.04 and WSL Ubuntu 20.04 on my PC.
I create a basic console application.

- Real Machine , Debug OK , Run OK , Cmd line OK
- WSL , Debug fail , Run OK , Cmd line OK

When i try to debug on WSL delphi deploy application with success but debugger is not started ,There is no message !!

What am i missing ?
I have followed the exactly same installation procedure for paserver on both systems

Delphi 10.4.2.
Windows 10 Professional

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: @fpiette No error Message

Comment: @Brian   NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         1

Comment: Do you know if there is a log of connection for paclient and paserver somewhere ?

Comment: Thanks @brian , i have installed WSL2  and i can debug !!! Great

Answer (score 1):

After update to WSL2 everything works fine .
I had to edit the batch running the GUI with x410 ( /public )
and the code to get server address export DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0

Thank you very much @Brian

```
start /B x410.exe /desktop /public
Ubuntu2004.exe run "if [ -z \"$(pidof xfce4-session)\" ]; then export DISPLAY=$(route.exe print | grep 0.0.0.0 | head -1 | awk '{print $4}'):0.0; xfce4-session; pkill '(gpg|ssh)-agent'; fi;"
```

Comment: The comments from Brian are no longer available.  Besides the batch file changes, and upgrading to WSL2, did you do anything else to correct the debugging problem on Linux?  I've tried 3 different distros and only Ubuntu seemed to work.